# How to get chapter name to appear in fancyhdr report?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, fancyhdr

I am trying to get the chapter to appear in the header, but it always just displays "CONTENTS".  The following is my demo code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{\today}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\cfoot{}
\rhead{}
\lhead{\leftmark}
\renewcommand {\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand {\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength\unitlength{1in}

\clearpage\phantomsection
\tableofcontents

\clearpage\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 1}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{2.125in}
  \centering
\framebox(2,2){\includegraphics[width=1.875in,height=1.875in,keepaspectratio]{infinity_80_gf_2010}}
\caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{2.125in}
  \centering
\framebox(2,2){\includegraphics[width=1.875in,height=1.875in,keepaspectratio]{Plus80_2010}}
\caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{2.125in}
  \centering
\framebox(2,2){\includegraphics[width=1.875in,height=1.875in,keepaspectratio]{comfort_achp_Puron}}
\caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[Hb]
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{2.125in}
  \centering
\framebox(2,2){\includegraphics[width=1.875in,height=1.875in,keepaspectratio]{infinity_80_gf_2010}}
\caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{2.125in}
  \centering
\framebox(2,2){\includegraphics[width=1.875in,height=1.875in,keepaspectratio]{Plus80_2010}}
\caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{2.125in}
  \centering
\framebox(2,2){\includegraphics[width=1.875in,height=1.875in,keepaspectratio]{comfort_achp_Puron}}
\caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image: result]

I want it to display "Chapter 1"

Comment: Why do use an `\addcontentsline`?

Comment: There is no clearance command to the header, so it will use the old `\contentsname` as **Chaptertitle**.

Comment: I based it off an earlier project I did where I was combining existing PDF files and creating a table of contents. I will try doing the \chapter approach and see if it fixes it.

Comment: If you don't want to use `\chapter`: Add `\markboth{Chapter 1}{}` after your `\addcontentsline`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I wanted to make the same statement as an alternative to my solution, but you were faster ;-)

Comment: I think \markboth{Chapter 1}{} is going to be best for my needs. Thank you all for your quick responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{\today}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\cfoot{}%
\rhead{}%
\lhead{\leftmark}
\renewcommand {\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand {\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}





\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength\unitlength{1in}

\clearpage\phantomsection
\tableofcontents

\clearpage\phantomsection
\chapter{My first chapter}%


%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 1}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{2.125in}
  \centering
\framebox(2,2){\includegraphics[width=1.875in,height=1.875in,keepaspectratio]{infinity_80_gf_2010}}
\caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{2.125in}
  \centering
\framebox(2,2){\includegraphics[width=1.875in,height=1.875in,keepaspectratio]{Plus80_2010}}
\caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{2.125in}
  \centering
\framebox(2,2){\includegraphics[width=1.875in,height=1.875in,keepaspectratio]{comfort_achp_Puron}}
\caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[Hb]
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{2.125in}
  \centering
\framebox(2,2){\includegraphics[width=1.875in,height=1.875in,keepaspectratio]{infinity_80_gf_2010}}
\caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{2.125in}
  \centering
\framebox(2,2){\includegraphics[width=1.875in,height=1.875in,keepaspectratio]{Plus80_2010}}
\caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{2.125in}
  \centering
\framebox(2,2){\includegraphics[width=1.875in,height=1.875in,keepaspectratio]{comfort_achp_Puron}}
\caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\blindtext[10]

\chapter{Number two}

\blindtext[10]


\end{document}
```

[image]